# Как при клике на кнопку изменить в ней текст?

Tags: javascript, html

Кнопка не одна, как сделать чтобы при клике изменялся текст именно этой кнопки?
Вот код:

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-lg add-to-order" value="Добавить к заказу" onclick="" id="123"></button>

<script type="text/javascript">
                    $('#123').click(function() {
                        $('#123').val('Добавлено к заказу');
                    });
                </script>
```

Так не получается

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
$('.add-to-order').click(function() {
  $(this).text('Добавлено к заказу')
         .css('background-color', '#ff0000');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add-to-order">Добавить к заказу</button>
<button class="add-to-order">Добавить к заказу</button>
<button class="add-to-order">Добавить к заказу</button>
```

Comment: Подскажите, как обратится к свойству background-color и делать кнопку другим цветом?

Comment: @Alexander добавил в ответ

Answer (score 2):

А так не подойдет?

```
<button class="add-to-order" onclick="this.innerText='Добавлено';">Добавить к заказу</button>
<button class="add-to-order" onclick="this.innerText='Добавлено';">Добавить к заказу</button>
<button class="add-to-order" onclick="this.innerText='Добавлено';">Добавить к заказу</button>
```

Дешево, сердито и без жквери.